# How to delete duplicate data with the resulting data collection in the Excel program?

Tags: excel

How to delete duplicate data with the resulting data collection in the Excel program

**EXAMPLE :**

```
 AAA     111
 BBB     555
 AAA     111
 CCC     222
```

**TO**

```
AAA     222
BBB     555
CCC     222
```

Comment: how is this data laid out? Is this in a string in one cell? Is that across columns? Also, what have you tried?

Comment: See image below - select both columns when deleting

Comment: You can use Pivot table for this. See my answer below.

Comment: HI.HUST NOW I HAVE POSTED NEW QUSTION FORM WITH MORE EXPLAIN  ABOUT THIS QUASTION

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you really want is consolidation. The process which you are describing can be achieved by using Pivot Tables.

- Assign suitable headers to your data if they are not there.
- Select Data as you have now.
- Choose >Insert>Pivot Tables.
- In "Row Labels" put the column having `AAA, BBB` etc.
- In "Values" section put the other column of which you need `SUM`.

Answer (score 1):

**Excel 2007 and above**

Bring your data in column, select column, and go to data > remove duplicates, that should do.

[image]

**Excel 2003**

Bring data in column, sort it in any order (ascending or descending). Use the formula as shown in picture. Delete all rows with zero.

[image]

In case you also want to sum the amount as well, there are two ways -

**With Pivot**

Create a Pivot on your data (You must have named columns for that, I have named them var1 and var2) - select the data, goto insert > pivot table.

[image]

It will automatically select range, and press OK, this will by default generate a pivot in new sheet

[image]

In new pivot fields, drag var1 to rows and var2 to values. By default (if all values are numeric), it will give you sum

[image]

**Without Pivot**

Create unique list of items by one of the methods above, and sum using sumif formula (as shown below) -

[image]

Comment: I ALSO WANT TO COLLECT THE AMOUNT IN THE SECOND COLUMN